# Add custom parameter for custom user role

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles

I added a new user role by `add_role()` function via my plugin's activation function. I would like to add an integer parameter to such custom role, for example, `score` parameter which the default value is 100.

How can I achieve adding such parameter?

Comment: Please read this post https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-user-roles-in-wordpress/

Comment: @GufranHasan the article does not mention anything about adding custom parameter.

Comment: The `WP_Role`/`WP_Roles` class doesn't currently support custom data, but you can use something like `add_option( 'role_name_score', 100 )` or `add_option( 'role_name_data', array( 'score' => 100, ... ) )`.

Comment: @SallyCJ this is a nice idea.

Comment: However, it's not user-specific. Need to find another solution.

Comment: Well, I thought you meant the *role* itself (e.g. `editor`) and not a *user* of that role.. :) And for user-specific, how about using a custom meta/field - e.g. `add_user_meta( 123, 'score', 100 )` (or maybe save an array of data) ? But you can still use the add/update_option to set the default `score`/value for all users of that role..